# Changing static text from right to left on text field

Tags: jquery

I found a code that adds an onkey function that concatenates with static text.
Im fairly new to coding in this area and I am not aware of how the operators and conditions work with jQuery, so my question is, how do I make it so that the input text would appear on the right side rather than the left side.

```
$("#staticTextId").on('keyup', function(){
    var str = $(this).val();
    var suffix = " static text";
    
    if(str.search(suffix) === -1){
        str += suffix;}
    
    var actualLength = str.length - suffix.length;
    
    $(this)
        // set the value
        .val(str.substr(0,actualLength) + suffix)
        // set cursor position
        .get(0).setSelectionRange(actualLength,actualLength);    
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h677zt4f/3/

PS: excuse me for not giving credits to the author as I have lost the link from where I found it on this platform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#staticTextId").on('keyup', function(){
    var str = $(this).val();
    var prefix = "static text ";
    var newVal = str.search(prefix) === -1 ? prefix += str : str;
    var actualLength = newVal.length;
    
    $(this)
        // set the value
        .val(newVal)
        // set cursor position
        .get(0).setSelectionRange(actualLength,actualLength);    
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Appreciate the logic that you have shared. Works like a charm!